# Adding phone number to customer creation page

Tags: magento2.3, customer

I want to add phone number to the customer creation page, since on of our users want's to contact people when they register to their webpage.

I did follow this guide (https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-custom-field-to-registration-page-magento-2/)
But as you can see (http://lommel.no/customer/account/create/) no phone number was added.

I did upgrade - dicompile - content:deploy - reindex and cleared cache. But nothing.

is there something wrong with the guide?

Magento version: 2.3
Theme: Porto

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you plz show your code what you have to Do ? paste all file particularly customer_account_create.xml

Comment: Cusotomer_account_create.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     layout="1column"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                  name="phone_number"
                  template="Magenest_CustomerAttribute::extra_field.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>

Comment: HAVE YOU FACE ANY ERROR DURING php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Not at all, no errors what's so ever. That's why is find this so weird

Comment: If no issue in your customer_account_create.xml  layout file it should show at least field in the Form, either it work or not.

Comment: If you look at the guide i was using, Is it correct to put it under app/code/custom_magento_module?

Comment: this guide is fine, you do mistake in copy paste

Comment: I checked the files and no issue with the copy paste

Comment: please verify custom attributed created in your DB customer EAV table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115714/discussion-between-hassan-ali-shahzad-and-jan-petter-havna).

Comment: What EAV table is it in and what should it be called?
Sorry, but as you properly understand I'm new with magento.
I'm using PhPMyAdmin

Comment: Is that working for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Modules Directory structure will be:

[image]

replace your Magenest/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_info_customer_phone_number" template="Magenest_CustomerAttribute::extra_field.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Did not work :(
http://lommel.no/customer/account/create/

Comment: zip and send module to me

Comment: Thank you for that, but how would I send that to you?

Comment: I had started chat

Comment: No, is not working for me yet